# Target Display Mode + Teleport with Thunderbolt iMac and Mac mini running Lion

Tags: imac, mac-mini, thunderbolt

I've set up Screen Sharing, so I can see Teleport is working... But I can't get it to work if I use Target Display Mode.

Here's what I tried:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> with Teleport's mouse on the iMac.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> with Teleport's mouse on the Mac mini.

Just doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Target Display Mode makes the iMac pretend to be a dumb monitor. That seems to make using Teleport irrelevant, as the mouse (connected to the Mac mini) should move across both screens with no issue at all.

Comment: the mac mini doesn't have its own stand-alone monitor.

Comment: Right. I was thinking laptop and typing mini. I'm not sure what the solution would be; from what you've stated, it should work.

Comment: yeah, the problem is that as soon as the imac goes in to target display mode the keyboard and mouse are offline (except Command-F2 and media player controls). I tried making the Mac mini Teleport server, but then I can't get the iMac in to target display mode. I wish apple would just automatically let me use the keyboard and mouse connected to the iMac if target display mode senses that the Mac mini doesn't have any. Thunderbolt should make this possible..